# Radiator valve will not close

Tags: valve, radiator

This summer, I had a leaking radiator valve be replaced by a plumber. He then fitted the existing thermostatic head on the new valve, as it worked fine. Now that it's winter, it appears that the new valve is not functioning well. The room temperature is around 20 degrees C with the head in its coldest position. The plumber claims he has too much other work to come and fix this anytime soon.
This is a picture of the valve:

[image]

I wonder if it is possible to adjust the valve by turning counterclockwise the brass-coloured hexagonal part with the pin in it? A little bit to begin with, say 90 degrees. I'd expect that the pin housing would move out a little, causing the thermostatic head to push the pin deeper and close the valve more. Is this something you can do without danger of breaking the valve or flooding the house?

Pictures of the sides of the part (thank you FreeMan for the suggestion). I live in Belgium.
[image][image]

Comment: Are there any markings on the valve indicating brand/model? That would allow someone to find instructions on these here interwebs and help you out...